# C++: Error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading, overloading

I have the following code:

```
int Array::getSize(){ 
   //do something
}
Movie Array::getMovie(int i){ 
   //do something
}

void Array::add(Movie* movie){
  //do something
}

Array& Array::operator+=(Array& movies){
  for (int i = 0; i < movies.getSize(); i++){
    add(&movies.getMovie(i));
  }
  return *this;

}
```

the += operator adds every element of `movies` to `this` collection
When I compile my program i get this error message:

```
Array.cc:40:29: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

   add(&movies.getMovie(i));

                         ^
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: *the += operator adds every element of movies to this collection*  -- Your `+=` does *not* do this.  If it did, the function to add would have a prototype similar to this: `add(Movie& movie)`.

Comment: It's not legal to use `&` with a temporary object.  However nobody can suggest a fix unless you show what is in the `add` function and show how you normally call the `add` function.  If that function adds the pointer instead of copying from the pointed-to location, that would be Very Bad. The solution will involve changing either the `add` or the `getMovie` function to be consistent, they should either both have value semantics or both have pointer semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Method getMovie returns an object. When you call getMovie, a temporay object is created as return. Taking a reference to this temporary object is not what you want because the object is destroyed at the end of the body of the for loop.
A solution is to create an object in getMovie (with new) and return the pointer to the new object. Adding this object pointer to the array. When the Array is not needed any more, delete the items in the Array.